# Piping with PowerShell in Office 365 Exchange and on-premises AD

Tags: powershell, exchange, active-directory, office365

We have a local AD domain synced with Exchange Online in Office 365.  I am trying to use PowerShell to get information that I need but keep getting an error and can’t seem to get the commands to work (pipe) properly together.

What I am trying to do is:

```
1)  Use GET-ADOBJECT to query my local AD for any user/person object in a specific
    OU and return the UserPrincipalName
2)  Pipe the returned UserPrincipalName to the GET-MAILBOX cmdlet (Exchange Online
    in Office 365) and retrieve any mailbox where RecipientTypeDetails equals
    “SharedMailbox”.  The output will them return UserPrincipalName
3)  Pipe the returned UserPrincipalName to GET-ADOBJECT and query my local AD again
    for any object where msExchRemoteRecipientType isn’t equal to 100
```

The combined PowerShell command looks something like:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter {(objectClass -eq "User") -And (objectCategory -eq "Person")} -SearchBase “OU=Test,DC=domain,DC=com” -Properties UserPrincipalName | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | ForEach-Object{Get-Mailbox -Identity $_.UserPrincipalName} | Where-Object {$_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SharedMailbox"} | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | ForEach-Object {Get-ADObject -Filter {(UserPrincipalName -eq $_.UserPrincipalName)} -SearchBase "OU=Test,DC=domain,DC=com" –Properties msExchRemoteRecipientType} | Where-Object {$_.msExchRemoteRecipientType -ne 100}
```

I’ve tried different variations but end up with the following error:

```
Get-ADObject : Property: 'UserPrincipalName' not found in object of type:
'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.

At line:1 char:356
+ Get-ADObject -Filter {(objectClass -eq "User") -And (objectCategory -eq "Person")} -SearchBase “OU=Test,DC=domain,DC=com” -Properties UserPrincipalName | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | ForEach-Object{Get-Mailbox -Identity $_.UserPrincipalName} | Where-Object {$_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SharedMailbox"} | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | ForEach-Object {Get-ADObject -Filter {(UserPrincipalName -eq $_.UserPrincipalName)} -Search Base "OU=Test,DC=domain,DC=com" –Properties msExchRemoteRecipientType} | Where-Object {$_.msExchRemoteRecipientType -ne 100}
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADObject], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Property: 'UserPrincipalName' not found in object of type:
  'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADObject
```

If I remove the last part (the last Get-ADObject portion):

```
ForEach-Object {Get-ADObject -Filter {(UserPrincipalName -eq $_.UserPrincipalName)} -Search Base "OU=Test,DC=domain,DC=com" –Properties msExchRemoteRecipientType} | Where-Object {$_.msExchRemoteRecipientType -ne 100}
```

I get the desired UserPrincipalName output.

My problem is piping the UserPrincipalName output from Get-Mailbox to Get-ADObject.  The reason that I am using “ForEach-Object” is that it fixed the problem when piping from Get-ADObject to Get-Mailbox but it isn’t working when piping Get-Mailbox to Get-ADObject.

I have tried many different ways to solve this but have not been successful.  Is there a way to pipe Get-Mailbox to Get-ADObject?  Or is there some other trick that can be used to get the desired output?  Can I make the “properties” that are returned from the first Get-ADObject query “pass thru” the Get-Mailbox cmdlet and then have those “properties” available as output to the second Get-ADObject query?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I have the same problem running the following example:

```
Get-Mailbox "john.doe@domain.com" | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | Get-ADObject {(UserPrincipalName -eq $_.UserPrincipalName)} -SearchBase "DC=domain,DC=com"
```

Is it possible to pipe from *GET-MAILBOX* to *GET-ADOBJECT*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use the $_ variable in a filter. The following works fine:

```
get-mailbox | foreach{$upn = $_.UserPrincipalName; Get-ADObject -Filter {UserPrincipalName -like $upn}}
```